# is it optimal to store pyspark dataframes in a dictionary, how does it work internally?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to optimize my code for best performance, I am working with about 35 dataframes in pyspark 2.4.0 using regular pyspark dataframe dot notation operations. I need to read them in dynamically based one some list of names of kafka topics. Right now I am saving the result in python dictionary where I map the topic name to the resulting dataframe.
How does it affect pyspark performance, query execution, lazy evaluation? Is it a bad practice? 
My guess is that only a pointer to pyspark dataframe is stored in the dictionary. Is it correct?

`d_dataframes = {"topic1": df1, "topic2":df2, "topic3": df3}`

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference. It's just the data frame object that you map (if execution is slow, that's because of something else).

Comment: Thank you. Sounds reasonable. @ernest_k